# Using sed to find a folder directory in a file and replacing with another directory

Tags: shell, sed

So I am trying to use a simple sed command in shell to find and replace a certain string in my bash file for an alias.

The alias is something like:

alias configure='cd /opt/Test/conf/server'

I want to replace /opt/Test/conf/server with /opt/Test/conf but am having difficulties with the syntax.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat my_bash_file.sh | sed 's#/opt/Test/conf/server#/opt/Test/conf#g'
```

Comment: This works, changed it to a sed -i instead of cat because cat did not change the file, just output the change to the screen.